# Warning on using std::strtoul to convert std::string to unsigned short. Any better option available?

Tags: c++, gcc, clang, c++14

I am using `C++ 14` on `clang` & `gcc`. I have an `std::string` which I need to convert to `unsigned short` I am doing it the following way.

```
unsigned short u_var = 1234;  //some default value
std::string str = "5678";      //some default value

u_var = (unsigned short) std::strtoul(str.c_str(), NULL, 0);
```

I found this from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28492110/convert-string-to-short-in-c).

**However, I get the following warning doing this**

```
Semantic issue
warning: use of old-style cast
```

The warning appears for both `clang` & `gcc`. **What is wrong in what I doing? Is there is a better way to do this without any risk or a warning?**

Also looking at the list of casting methods [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stoul), there seems to be no cast option available for `std::string` to `unsigned short`.

Comment: Does `static_cast<unsigned short>(std::strtoul(str.c_str(), NULL, 0);)` help? It doesn't complain about conversion, it complains about the syntax.

Comment: It's warning you that the cast you used, whose meaning is well-defined and perfectly appropriate as you've used it, might not be appropriate in some other context.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is with the C-style cast (they are kinda risky). Use `static_cast` instead. Like:

```
u_var = static_cast< unsigned short >( std::strtoul(str.c_str(), NULL, 0) );
```

I'd also use `std::stoul` instead of `std::strtoul`, if it's possible (it's C++11)

Comment: seems like stoul is not supported in C++11 but yes, the static cast takes away the warning

Comment: @SegmentationFault - `stoul` _is_ introduced in C++11, so you need to compile with a "modern" compiler and `-std=c++11`. At least according to `cppreference.com`.

Answer (score 2):

`(unsigned short) <expression>` is a [C-style explicit cast](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/explicit_cast), which is potentially unsafe as it tries to perform various conversions including `reinterpret_cast` and `const_cast`.

You should use `static_cast` for numerical conversions:

```
u_var = static_cast<unsigned short>(std::strtoul(str.c_str(), NULL, 0));
```

Answer (score 1):

> The warning appears for both clang & gcc. What is wrong in what I doing? Is there is a better way to do this without any risk or a warning?

compiler gives you an advise that its safier to use c++ style cast: `static_cast<unsigned short>(...)` instead of c style cast: `(unsigned short)...`

If you are using C++14 then you may consider using `std::stoul` function, in case of error it throws exception, which is easier to work with.

> Also looking at the list of casting methods here, there seems to be no cast option available for std::string to unsigned short.

there is no standard cast for converting std::string to unsinged short, but with boost::lexical_cast it is possible: your code would look as follows :

```
try
{
   u_var = boost::lexical_cast<unsigned short>(str);
}
catch(const boost::bad_lexical_cast &)
{
   // error
}
```

Comment: so, do you recommend that using `std::stoul` is better than `std::strtoul` ?

Comment: I dont have the option to use boost here. I have to strictly stay within `std::` options

Comment: @SegmentationFault yes - that is because error checking for strtoul is not so obvious - you can find on this here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1640720/how-do-i-tell-if-the-c-function-atoi-failed-or-if-it-was-a-string-of-zeros. If you consider using std::stoul then check if your stl library actually supports it, as far as I remember android NDK does not.